# Watir-webdriver : Accessing elements using Indexing

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to access a li element using indexing

```
<div class="item-list">
<ul>
<li class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
<li class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
<li class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
<li class="views-row views-row-4 views-row-even">
<li class="views-row views-row-5 views-row-odd">
<li class="views-row views-row-6 views-row-even">
<li class="views-row views-row-7 views-row-odd">
<li class="views-row views-row-8 views-row-even">
<li class="views-row views-row-9 views-row-odd views-row-last">
</ul>
</div>
```

The code I am using is

```
@browser.div(:class,'item-list').ul.li(:index => 2)
```

The question is : These are elements on a page and I will be using a loop to access each element. I thought using indexing will solve the problem but when I write my code and execute it I get the following error

```
expected #<Watir::LI:0x2c555f80 located=false selector={:index=>2, :tag_name=>"li"}> to exist (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

How can I access these elements using Indexing.

Comment: have you tried .lis[2] ?

Comment: It works !!!!! Can you please explain why it is not able to access the element using li(:index => 2). Thanks for the help pguardiario

Comment: Using "lis" plural after the div locator creates an array of all li elements underneath.  What you're saying is: make an array out of all the li elements within this specific div, now tell me which one is third([2]).  Arrays use 0-indexing, so [2] gives you the third li.  My Answer below shows an ".each do" method which works the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've got class-naming that nice, forget indexing!  Do a partial match on the "views-row" parameter:

```
@browser.li(:class => /views-row-1/)
```

This can easily be parameterized for looping (although I don't know what you're doing with the information so this loop will not be very exciting).

```
x = 0
until x==9
  x+=1
  puts  @browser.li(:class => /views-row-#{x}/).text
end
```

You could also blindly loop through the li's contained in your `div` if you'd like:

```
   @browser.div(:class,'item-list').lis.each do |li|
      puts li.text
   end
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the Watir wiki, Watir [supports](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/HTML+Elements+Supported+by+Watir) the `:index` method on the `li` element. So unless it is a bug in watir-webdriver, I think the index should work.

You may want to try the [watir mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/watir-general) to see if this is a problem for others.